# solr pdf search highlighting issue

Tags: pdf, solr, lucene, lucene-highlighter

solr v6.5:-
I have 2 pdf files indexed in a solr core. When I search for a keyword it is getting found in the document, however, the highlighting works for one document and not the other. For ex: when I search for "panic" which is there in one of the documents. I get the search result with highlighting. But when I search for "epsilon", I get a result that says it has been found with the document information etc, however, the highlighting for this document is not working.
Heres whats been added/changed in managed_schema.xml:

```
    .
    .
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
.
. 
    <field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="content" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    .
    .
    <copyField source="content" dest="_text_"/>
```

And, solrconfig.xml snippet is as follows:

```
.
.
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
.
.
```

Comment: Please check how the word "epsilon" is indexed in Solr using a search query and check whether it contains any space or capital letters in it. And also check what kind of analyzers you are using for "_\_text\__"  field(Both "index" and for "query")? add this in question too so that the issue can be found.

Comment: @Riya I am pretty sure that the word I am searching for is "as is" in the document as well. Also, have made an edit including the fieldtype details

Comment: Once again, searching and highlighting works for one pdf doc(small size pdf file). However, searching works but not highlighting for the other pdf(comparatively larger in size). If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Used the

> hl.maxAnalyzedChars=aLargeEnoughValue

parameter in the query and it gives me highlighting for search words which are farther down the doc. The default value for this parameter is 51200.

Take-away: Large docs when indexed in Solr would give +ve results for SEARCH, however, highlighting could be null/nothing. This happens if the word searched for is farther down the document. Simply increasing the value of hl.maxAnalyzedChars does the job.